# Question on Garling Approach to Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L:K$ be a finite field extension.

Let $G=\operatorname{Aut}(L:K)$, so $G$ is the group of all ring automorphisms on the field $L$ which fix the field $K$.

Let $K'$ be the subfield of $L$ fixed by the set $G$, so $K'$ and $K$ are not necessarily the same fields.

I can show if $L:K$ is normal and separable, as well as finite, then $K = K'$.

However, if $L:K$ is not normal or not separable, then I can't figure out if $K$ is a proper subfield of $K'$ or if $K'$ is a proper subfield of $K$. It seems the former must hold in order to support those edge cases where $L = K$ or there are no proper intermediate fields between $K$ and $L$. This my question.

CONTEXT:

1> I have been working from the book, "A Course in Galois Theory" by D.J.H Garling, as my main source for many years as an amateur.
The approach in this book seems "nonstandard". In particular, his statement of the fundamental theorem is more general than others I see online and the definitions of separability seem "nonstandard". At any rate, it has my favorite source for many years. In the remarks at the end of the proof of the fundamental theorem, he concludes with, "Finally, we do not need normality or separability. But if $L:K$ is a Galois extension <read: finite, normal and separable>, then $K = K'$ and the result is corresponding neater."

2> I am retired after working many decades in the computer industry. I do all my stuff in Word Equation Editor and don't know the cool "scripting language" used on this site. I really don't want to learn another programming language (even if it just scripting as it reminds me of working).

Given these, I apologize in advance if this post is too wordy or off-base.

Any replies will be greatly appreciated, however. Thank you.

Comment: Obviously $K\subset K'$. $a\in L$ is a root of $\prod_{b\in Ga} (x-b)\in K'[x]$ which is separable and which splits completely in $L$. It implies that $L/K'$ is normal and separable. So if $L/K$ is not normal or not separable then $K\subsetneq K'$.

Comment: The cool scripting language is basically just putting dollar signs around most of the math you wrote to be honest.

Comment: I confess I do not understand the product indexing. What is b? Is Ga, a right coset perhaps? Anyway, I am further looking for an answer which does not reply on "roots" of polynomials. It seems the fundamental theorem "applies" to polynomials and roots and solvability and all that cool stuff downstream, but its "root" is a statement about groups and fields.

Comment: I forgot in my hast, it is impossible to define separability without roots of polynomials. My apologies. This does not mean I understand the reply, but I shall work on your feedback.

Comment: $Ga=\{ g(a),g\in G\}$ the orbit of $a$ under the action of $G$

Comment: Interesting question. Besides, continuing the remark of @Arkady, it is not too complicated to"script" elementary formulas with Latex, for example a quadratic equation `$ax^2+bx+c=0$` and its solutions `$x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$` giving $x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x\in K'=\operatorname{Fix}_L(G)=\operatorname{Fix}_L(\operatorname{Aut}(L/K))$, then equivalently $\varphi(x)=x$ („$\varphi$ fixes $x$“ or „$x$ is a fix-point of $\varphi$“) for all automorphisms $\varphi\in\operatorname{Aut}(L/K)$, but those in particular all fix all the values in $K$ per definition. Hence we get an inclusion $K\subseteq K'$.

(If $K/L$ is a galois field extension (meaning algebraic (which follows from finite), normal and seperable), we get an equality from the fundamental theorem of Galois theory as you have claimed.)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $K\subset K'$.

For $a\in L$ let $Ga = \{g(a),g\in G\}$ the orbit of $a$ under the action of $G$.

Then $a$ is a root of the polynomial $$\prod_{b\in Ga} (x-b)\in L[x]$$ **which is in fact in $K'[x]$.**

This polynomial is separable and it splits completely in $L$. It means that $L/K'$ is normal and separable.

If $L/K$ is not normal or not separable then $K\ne K'$ ie. $K\subsetneq K'$.